# How can I talk to the people of main site?

Tags: discussion

How can I talk to the people of main site?
I want to talk to the teachers of this main site.

I want to meet Khan,  J.R and other teachers.
I am sorry to ask this useless question here but I really need to speak to them.

I want to know the chat room where "Khan"is available, and other members or teacher too.
Thanks in advance if you help me in this problem. 
Tell me about meta chat or chat room , where I can speak to Khan sir J.R sir , and other teachers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a question about an aspect of the English language.

Comment: Yes, I have already said sorry in advance but I want to meet them in their chat rooms please help me to solve the problem. After that , you can delete this question.

Comment: Actually, I always ask tiny questions about grammar here but I thought that I will not ask tiny questions on main site that's what I want to know about their chat rooms where I will simply ask them about English grammar. I don't want to mess up the name of this site , having shared the simplest questions.

Comment: Please go to the main chat room of ELL ("[ELL's Cabin](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22937/ells-cabin)"). If a user has been active recently, you can ping him by typing '@' and the first letter(s) of the user name, which then can be selected from a list. It is that user's choice whether he wants to respond. For questions about language learning, you could also try the "[Language Overflow](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24938/language-overflow)" chat room. You will find *many more* users there than the two you mentioned.

Comment: I also went there but I couldn't find Khan there.  Khan solves my tiny problems because he is also from Pakistan and me too. He can understand my problems here.  Otherwise a native speaker or another teacher can't help me to settle my tiny questions.  J.R and Khan clear my concepts,  I want to stay connected with them in their chat rooms where they spend their free time sometimes.

Answer (score 12):

The Stack Exchange is not set up where users can contact other individual users directly. As others have said in their comments, the best way to contact an individual user would be a chat room, but not all users frequent the chat rooms, and they are under no obligation to do so.

While it's nice that you've gotten help from a few users, the Stack Exchange model is really set up where you ask a questions **to the community**, not to one or two individual users. The entire community will grow stronger that way.